# What's the best translation for the word "nest" in a technical context?

Tags: перевод, математика

What's the best Russian translation for the word "nest" in a technical context?

For example:

> f[x] applies f to x. f[f[x]] applies f to f[x], or effectively nests the application of f. It’s common to want to repeat or nest a function.

This simple term, "nest", doesn't seem to have an exact equivalent in Russian.

Comment: translations are offtopic here, you might try asking at https://www.proz.com

Comment: You could try opening English wiki page about nested functions (or one that has a section about them) and navigate to Russian version of the page. That's probably the best option for translating technical terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some language used to describe function nesting:

- Композиция функций
- Вложенная / внутренняя функция

Comment: Композиция does not suggest use of *the same* function repeatedly. I think итерация функции works better. Even in English, iteration sounds better than "nesting".

Comment: @KCd  *Композиция does not suggest use of the same function repeatedly* - neither does Nest(ing). Specificaly it's nothing about *repeatedly*.  In application programming,: a nested function is obviously "вложенная функция" (usually means a function defined in the body of another one). Внутренняя would be equal to an "inner" one (as in inner/outer).

Comment: @KCd  The Q however seems to use the term in a different context like `f(g(x))` which indeed looks like a [Function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) (personally I have no idea if they use the word "Nest" in this context at all).
Thus the A seems to be perfectly fine - it's just the Q is a bit confusing (the whole quote does not even look like a perfect English and the very use of `[]` in `f[f[x]]` looks suspicious - i.e. it could be some specific area/programming-language with drifted conventions).

Comment: @seven-phases-max I agree that if composition of different functions is intended then итерация is a bad translation.  The OP's use of f[f[x]] and the word "repeat" is what made the question seem to me like the intention was to plug the same function into itself over and over, which is what's usually called function iteration.